# Scrapy Returns Different Results between Shell and Spider

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, scrapy, python-3.7

I am attempting to get the mini-bio from the top of the following page:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein

With scrapy shell I'm able to perform the following:

```py
C:\Users\broke\Documents\DataViz Projects>scrapy shell https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein

...
[s]   request    <GET https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein>
[s]   response   <200 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein>
...

In [1]:  response.xpath('//div[@id="mf-section-0"]/p[text() or normalize-space(.)=""]').extract()
Out[1]:
['<p class="mw-empty-elt">\n\n</p>',
 '<p><b>César Milstein</b>, <a href="/wiki/Order_of_the_Companions_of_Honour" title="Order of the Companions
of Honour">CH</a>, <a href="/wiki/Royal_Society" title="Royal Society">FRS</a><sup id="cite_ref-frs_2-1" clas
s="reference"><a href="#cite_note-frs-2">[2]</a></sup> (8 October 1927 – 24 March 2002) was an <a href="/wiki
/Argentinian" class="mw-redirect" title="Argentinian">Argentinian</a> biochemist in the field of <a href="/wi
ki/Antibody" title="Antibody">antibody</a> research.<sup id="cite_ref-4" class="reference"><a href="#cite_not
e-4">[4]</a></sup>
...
</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-12" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-12">[12]</a></sup><s
up id="cite_ref-13" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-13">[13]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-14" class="refe
rence"><a href="#cite_note-14">[14]</a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-15" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-15">
[15]</a></sup></p>']
```

However, the following parser code in my spider is returning an empty list when passed that URL:

```py
    def get_mini_bio(self,response):
        """ Get the winner's bio text and photo"""
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['image_urls']=[]
        img_src = response.xpath('//table[contains(@class,"infobox")]//img/@src')
        if img_src:
            item['image_urls'] = ['https:{}'.format(img_src[0].extract())]
        mini_bio = ''
        #paras = '\n\n'.join(response.xpath('//div[@id="mw-content-text"]//p[text() or normalize-space(.)=""]').extract())
        mini_bio = response.xpath('//div[@id="mf-section-0"]/p[text() or normalize-space(.)=""]').extract()
        self.logger.warning("mini_bio received {} as a result.".format(mini_bio))
        yield
```

Output:

```
2019-05-28 01:52:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_M
ilstein> (referer: None) ['cached']
2019-05-28 01:52:59 [nwinners_minibio] WARNING: mini_bio received [] as a result.
```

Note the commented line in the parser, that xpath will return a set of paragraphs that include the desired paragraph (the paragraph inside of the 'mf-section-0' div), so the paragraph does appear to be being rendered. However, it will also include all the other paragraphs in the text section as well without enough information to differentiate across other similar pages.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting different results between the shell and the spider, and how I can get the same results in the spider as I am getting in the shell?

Comment: You could try writing the response contents of both responses to two files (response.body contains the response as bytes), and see if there are differences between them.

Comment: Yes, the body is different, but why would the shell and the spider return different response bodies for the same URL?

Comment: Have you checked in the spider if the source URL is the same? (`response.url == 'https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein'`).

Comment: They are the same, I checked via several methods, one I logged the URL:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein

And this confirmed the debugging data included in my question: 

From shell:
[s]   request    <GET https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein>
[s]   response   <200 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein>

From the Spider:
2019-05-28 01:52:59 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_M
ilstein> 
and
file.write(str(response.url))

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A9sar_Milstein